# How to fix these undefined values?

Tags: javascript

So I have a function that I need to pass 3 values, but my values are allways 0 if I don't enter them, and undefined if enter them. How to fix this issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calculate Area</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Enter Dimensions</h4>
    <input id="a" type="text" name=""><br>
    <input id="b" type="text" name=""><br>
    <input id="c" type="text" name=""><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="calculate()" value="Calculate">

    <div id="output"></div>


    <script>

        var a = Number(document.querySelector('#a').value);
        var b = Number(document.querySelector('#b').value);
        var c = Number(document.querySelector('#c').value);

        function calculate(a, b, c){
            //console.log(a);
            //console.log(b);
            //console.log(c);
            return 2*(a*b + a*c + b*c);
        }

        var p = calculate(a, b, c);

        document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = `<h4>Area = ${p}</h4>`;



    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Move those three lines that get the `<input>` values to **inside** the `calculate()` function.

Comment: But then I'm not passing values to calculate function, and my task is to pass the values as arguments of function

Comment: You're not passing anything into the function when you call it anyway (as an event handler). As it is, your code runs before the page has even finished loading, so there's nothing in the `<input>` fields yet.  You can write a second function that you call when the button is clicked, then *that* function can get the `<input>` values and pass them to `calculate()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get value from elements and set it to `#output` element each time `calculate` function is called. Check out my solution below.

```js
var aElement = document.querySelector('#a');
var bElement = document.querySelector('#b');
var cElement = document.querySelector('#c');
var outputElement = document.querySelector('#output');

function updateArea () {
    var a = Number(aElement.value);
    var b = Number(bElement.value);
    var c = Number(cElement.value);
    
    var res = calculate(a, b, c);
    
    outputElement.innerHTML = `<h4>Area = ${res}</h4>`;
}

function calculate (a, b, c) {
    return 2*(a*b + a*c + b*c);
}
```

```html
<h4>Enter Dimensions</h4>
<input id="a" type="text" name=""><br>
<input id="b" type="text" name=""><br>
<input id="c" type="text" name=""><br>
<input type="button" onclick="updateArea()" value="Calculate">
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but my definition of calculate function needs to be like this: ``` function calculate(a, b, c){} ```

Comment: @AleksLazic You can use another wrapping function, check it out in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are collecting the value of a, b and c at the beginning of the program. At first, the input boxes don't have any value, so the value of a, b and c is undefined. So collect the value when the submit button is clicked.

Try this approach:

```
function calculate(){
    var a = Number(document.querySelector('#a').value);
    var b = Number(document.querySelector('#b').value);
    var c = Number(document.querySelector('#c').value);

    var p = 2*(a*b + a*c + b*c);

    document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = '<h4>Area = ${p}</h4>';
}
```